# Objects with references to other objects of same class C#

Tags: c#

I have a class, I would like to contain a list/vector/whatever of pointers to other objects of the same class. An object of the class would represent a coordinate, and the list would contain references to other coordinates that are connected to this one... if that makes sense.

I'm used to C++, where I would have something like:

```
class MyClass
{
    private:
        std::vector<const MyClass*> vec;
};
```

I'm trying to do something like the above in C#, but I can't tell how to do it. Do I have to use the *unsafe* keyword somehow, so I can use pointers, or is there another smarter way to implement something like this in C#?

Comment: I think you need a simple `private List<MyClass> vec;`. Whenever you add something to that list, it's just a reference anyway, so if you modify it inside `MyClass` or outside, it will change at all places.

Comment: @MarioVernari Not really.  They are either _reference_ or _value_ types.  Generally one should not use the term _pointer_ unless you are referring to `unsafe` contexts.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just setup the class with a List/Enumerable or whatever of you type, so something like:

```
public class Cake
{
    // public
    public IEnumerable<Cake> Cakes { get; set; }

    // private
    private IEnumerable<Cake> cakes; 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For List

```
class MyClass
{
    public List<MyClass> Vec { get { return vec; } set { vec = value }
    private List<MyClass> vec;
}
```

Comment: You can also make that a little cleaner by ditching the private backing field and using an auto property: public List<MyClass> Vec { get; set; }